# How to retrieve data using firstValueFrom - Angular 13?

Tags: angular, http

In my userService, I have:

```
async getUserData() {
    const user = await this.afAuth.currentUser;
    const token = await user?.getIdToken();
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
    const url = "...";
    const response = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get(url, { headers }));
    return response;
  }
```

and in my ngOnInit of a certain component I have:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user.getUserData().then((res) => console.log(res));
  }
```

I can log the returned object ok, I see its properties, but I have no idea why I cannot access the property data of it. I can only access constructor, hasOwnProperty, isPrototypeOf, etc...

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: same exact problem - using Angular 14 and RxJS 7.4.0

Answer (score 1):

You did not type the get request like this:

`this.http.get<MyDataStructure>(url, { headers })`

If you do not type it, the signature of get will be: `Observable<Object>`.

If you do type it with `T` it will be `Observable<T>`.

So the data is actually there. TypeScript just does not know it is there and thus the IDE does not give the respective hints.

If you do not want to define the type specifically you can use `this.http.get<any>(url, { headers })` to work around it.

Comment: There is not need to give a type to the [get method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) so that is not the error. the method has enough overloads to not require it.

Comment: The overload for this scenario is `Object` still, since he did not specify `responseType` nor `observe`. And Object contains the attributes he is seeing, while other attributes do actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

How about using plain rxjs for the job instead of mixing promises in there?

When using angular, the best approach is to surrender to [Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

You could change your service function to

```
getUserData() {
    ...
    return this.http.get(url, { headers }))
  }
```

and in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.user.getUserData().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => 
    {
      console.log(res))
    });
  }
```

Comment: While it may not be bad advice to use instead, it probably won't fix his issue as the Observable is still typed as `Object`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Type `Object` we can see that the OP has not provided types for the shared code. But I agree that enforcing types would make the code even better.

Comment: Iw works great as well @TheFabio. Tks a lot!!